# Best way to use the APRS.fi API to populate Google Maps

Tags: php, json, google-maps-api-3

APRS.fi outputs their API calls in JSON format. I'd like to use this output to build markers in the Google Maps API. Has anyone been doing this successfully? PHP is fine if that is the way to go but maybe someone has developed a method with out it.